# Storing data on the hard-disk so that it's accessible by the current process only

Tags: c++, c, file, process, daemon

i'm making a daemon process in C (Visual Studio). Basically i just get an .exe in the end which, once launched, will run until the computer shuts down (let's assume i'm using Windows though the question is valid for other OS too).

The process has an output which i choose to store in some files. The reason i'm storing this output in files and not in memory is because: what if the user kills the process? Then all data goes down the drain if it's in memory. The only problem is: i don't want the user to be able to modify the files my process is producing.

Is there a way i can protect files to only be accessible (or at least modifiable) by the process that created them?

One way which seems pretty inconvenient: run process with admin privileges and write to a location accessible only by the admin but not by the current user (inconvenient because i have to rely on the fact that the current user is not the admin)

Is this a common problem? Does it have a standard/known solution other than the workaround described above?

Comment: POSIX provides flags for opening files exclusively, but it's at least OS dependent, if it's supported.

Comment: If your file is open for writing, another program will not be able to modify it (in Windows, in other operating systems you will need to explicitly lock the files).

Comment: And if the user is admin, you can use a variety of ways in order to ensure that your files are not altered between runs of your program.

Comment: @frp this is brilliant, i wish i had thought of it!